# How to change DNS on macOS CLI (if i don't know interface name)?

Tags: network, command-line, vpn, dns

macOS (Catalina) and I want to start IKEv2 VPN client (CLI). Bad luck, ipsec can't change DNS servers. I can add UpDown script and run several commands on VPN up/down.

For example, I like `networksetup -setdnsservers <interface> <DNS>`, but there is a problem. I need to send this script to users who will use my VPN server. And I don't know what interface they are using to go to the Internet.

Is it any way to change **current** DNS servers on macOS by CLI commands?

Comment: Can't you just determine the active interface first?

Comment: Here is how you can find the active interface https://www.kittell.net/code/mac-osx-terminal-get-active-interface/  Untested by me.

Comment: @pemby It is brilliant idea to find working interface by default route! Thank you. I'll add it as a part of my script.